# android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true" doesn't work with twilight app

Tags: android, security, android-manifest, penetration-testing

I'm testing an application where `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true"` is declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` for every activity. When I run overlay twilight, my app still works. Did anyone have similar problem?

I'm testing on devices with Android 6.0 and 8.0, with and without root, testing with two types of overlays.

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Answer (score 2):

`android:filterTouchesWhenObscured` is an attribute you apply on `View`s in your layouts, not on activities in your manifest.

Comment: Do you know how to do it for flutter?

Comment: Hey @SarthakSolanki does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60108255/where-to-add-androidfiltertoucheswhenobscured-true-in-flutter-app