# Where to add android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = 'true' in flutter app

Tags: android, flutter

Where to add android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = 'true' in flutter app.  I couldn't find any answer with flutter perspective. I need to prevent my app from tabjacking for that I need to add`android:filterTouchesWhenObscured = 'true'`

But couldn't find any way to do it in flutter

Comment: There's seems to be an open issue for it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40422

Comment: Flutter doesn't support this yet. :/ Google's own products are not synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible with flutter, but only globally. You can set this property for the applications root view and it will affect the whole application.

Kotlin code sample:

```
val view = findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content).rootView
view.filterTouchesWhenObscured = true
```

Add this code in your `MainActivity` (for example in `onStart`) and touches will be globally disabled for the whole app if it appears to be obscured.

Comment: is it legit solution to use in production ?